# How can I keep a java app that updates a database running?

Tags: java, sql-server, web

I'm currently working on a simple webapp that shows the health of a device for a project. Its fairly simple I'm just displaying data from a database. Currently hosting it on firebase.

I've been asked to make a java program that stores data in a database at specific timepoints, this database will then be used for the webapp display. I can do this but I'm a little lost when it comes to hosting the web app.

How can I keep the java program running and updating the database when someone navigates to the webapp.

If anyone could suggest a direction to proceed it would be really appreciated. I apologize if this doesn't follow SO guidelines on questions. I'm new to the computer science world.

Comment: You may host it on Heroku (free plan based on a few conditions) or AWS (free for the first year or you may write a serverless app and probably stay in the free range).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at AWS. I only need it live for a month or so.